# Haskell: Transposition on a list of strings

Tags: haskell, recursion

New to Haskell and the language has been fun so far.  I am hoping for a good hint rather than an answer as I am enjoying the mind-altering that is Haskell.

**Question:** I have a list of strings and I would like to transpose them.

```
let x = ["hello", "world"]
```

would become

```
["hw", "eo", "lr", "ll", "od"]
```

What I have so far is this:

```
   transposeString :: [a] -> [a]
   transposeString ([]:_) = []
   transposeString x = (map head x) : transposeString (map tail x)
```

I definitely know there is something wrong with the type signature.  My rational is that

```
Let y = ["wow", "top"]
map head y
```

returns "wt" so recursing this on the rest of the list would work?

Thank you in advance for any hints.

Comment: Regarding the type signature, consider that `[a] -> [a]` includes `[Int] -> [Int]`. Would it make sense to ever do `transposeString [1,2,3]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mind that you do not have to provide a type signature: the Haskell compiler can derive one. If you put your implementation in a file:

```
transposeString ([]:_) = []
transposeString x = (map head x) : transposeString (map tail x)
```

and query the type with `:t` in `ghci`, it returns:

```
*Main> :t transposeString 
transposeString :: [[b]] -> [[b]]
```

This makes perfect sense:

1. you transpose a matrix, which is a list of lists. `[[b]]` is a list of lists of `b` elements; and
2. you can derive it from the implementation yourself: `map head x` means that *elements* of `x` must be a list (`[b]`) since we perform a mapping, we have to nest the list one additional level so `[[b]]`. The same for `tail`.

As far as I know, your implementation is correctly. You can specialize it by saying that `[b] ~ String`, thus adding a type signature for `String`s:

```
transposeString :: [String] -> [String]
transposeString ([]:_) = []
transposeString x = (map head x) : transposeString (map tail x)
```

which again makes sense because `String ~ [Char]` thus `b ~ Char`. But there is not much point in specializing a functions type: you better always use the most generic type signature. In this case `[[b]] -> [[b]]`.

Comment: Thank you! This works!  I'm still unable to get it to work for my particular situation (comments in a post below), but this answers my question.

Answer (score 2):

One point of note. Your type signature for `tranposeString` allows to accept a flat list as an argument. Tranposing a `[String]` works because `[String]`s are really just `[[Char]]`s, but what happens when you try to call `transposeString` on an `[Int]`? After all, the type signature allows for it.

On a side note, I ask you, given your current function, what would happen if your called `transposeString []`?

Comment: Another interesting case is `transposeString ["hello", "mars"]`, which in a few steps involves `["o", ""]`.

Comment: It's an infinite recursion of empty lists.  I'm working on that as well! haha. It's one small function in a bigger program.

Chi's point is exactly what I'm working on now because I have the situation ["ABCD", "EFGH", "IJKL" ..."YZ"] where there are 4 characters in each string but the last.  It throws an exception due to, I'm assuming, lazy evaluation.

Comment: Sample Output for kicks: [],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]^Z,[]
[1]+  Stopped                 ghci

Answer (score 0):

Do remember `String` is `[Char]`

```hs
"abc" == 'a' : 'b' : 'c' : []
```

From here you can use traversable nature of lists:

```hs
transpose :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
transpose mat = getZipList $ sequenceA $ map ZipList mat

test' = transpose [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] -- == [[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]]
test'' = transpose ["abc", "deg", "klm"] -- == ["adk","bel","cgm"]
```

You can also check default implementation of `transponse` in haskell doc
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/Data.OldList.html#transpose

```hs
transpose               :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
transpose []             = []
transpose ([]   : xss)   = transpose xss
transpose ((x:xs) : xss) = (x : [h | (h:_) <- xss]) : transpose (xs : [ t | (_:t) <- xss])
```